# Pairwise difference of MultiIndex column DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with MultiIndex columns like the following:

```
columnIdx1 = ["M1", "M2", "M3", "M4"]
columnIdx2 = ["pos", "neg"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(1000, 8), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([columnIdx1, columnIdx2]))
```

Then I calculate the mean of this with `df.mean()`, resulting in the same columns but a single row.

A:

```
     M1       M2       M3       M4
pos neg  pos neg  pos neg  pos neg
  1   8    2   7    3   6    4   5
```

Now I want to calculate the difference of each `neg` and `pos` like this:

B:

```
M1 M2 M3 M4
 7  5  3  1
```

My first thought was to transform the columnIdx1 columns to row indexes, but I found no way:

```
   pos neg
M1   1   8
M2   2   7
M3   3   6
M4   4   5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshaping and then subtract columns:

```
df = df.mean().unstack()
df['diff'] = df['neg'] - df['pos']
print (df)

         neg       pos      diff
M1  0.023254  0.017009  0.006245
M2 -0.028798 -0.054146  0.025349
M3 -0.007544 -0.013178  0.005634
M4  0.049680 -0.046202  0.095882
```